# jQuery running at the same time when page loading

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I need your help. I have a jquery code which is working nice after I first load the page and as a second step check the checkbox. In background function updateSg(opts) invokes the submit.php which results a Json.

But I would like to solve when I open the page, the checkbox input tag gets the checked value from URL, and the checkbox is checked but the jquery code is not run. I have to uncheck and check again for the code running.

Could you give me a help that the code is executed with the page loading together.

Thanks,
Atti

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="filter">
  <h2>Filter</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sg" name="sg" checked>
    <label for="sg">Something</label>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

<script>
  var getsg = "something";

  function makeTable(data){
       var tbl_body = "";
       $.each(data, function(k,v) {
         tbl_body += getsg;
       })
       return tbl_body;
  }

  function getSgFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      if(this.checked){
        opts.push(this.name);
      }
    });
    return opts;
  }

  function updateSg(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(records){
        $('div#result').html(makeTable(records));
      }
    });
  }

  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getSgFilterOptions();
    updateSg(opts);
  });

  updateSg();

  </script>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The checked attribute should do the trick.

Comment: I'm using chrome but of course it should be a browser independent solution.
I don't understand how I can use the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the checkbox is checked at first place.

Next, your `updateSg()` function does not provide postData for ajax when your page is loaded (therefore **filterOpts** is empty).

Try this:

```
<script>
  var getsg = "something";
  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");

  function makeTable(data){
      var tbl_body = "";
      $.each(data, function(k,v) {
          tbl_body += getsg;
      });
      return tbl_body;
  }  

  function callAjax(opts){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
              $('div#result').html(makeTable(records));
          }
      });
  }

  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
      getSgFilterOptions();
  });

  function getSgFilterOptions(){
      if($checkboxes.length){
          var opts = [];
          $checkboxes.each(function(){
              if(this.checked){
                  opts.push(this.name);
              }
          });
          callAjax(opts);
      }
  }

  getSgFilterOptions();

</script>
```

Comment: It seems to work properly.
Thanks for your quick help.